# All my harddrives are around 10 MB/s read/write

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hp

I have a HP N54L MicroServer (AMD N54L, 4GB RAM) running on Lubuntu (doesn't really matter happens on Ubuntu too). In there are 4 HDDS each 1 TB, Samsung HD103SJ. I tried every single BIOS setting (AHCI, IDE) as well as other settings, but the read and write speed of those hdds is around 10 MB/s. I'm measuring this with dd. I can't figure out whats the problem.

Comment: Add `bs=1m` to the dd command and test again.

Comment: Hello! I already tried this...

Comment: Sounds a bit like a misaligned partition or tiny inode size. What's the output of `tune2fs -l /dev/sdaX | grep Inode` (replace sdaX with one of the drives, or the volume if using LVM)

Comment: @ChrisS All 4 drives are showing this:

Inode count:            61054976
Inodes per group:       8192
Inode blocks per group: 512
Inode size:             256

Answer (score 3):

If you do not set buffer size (`bs`, `obs` or `ibs`), it defaults to 512. If you have a 4k drive this is  inefficient. Also moving small chunks of data and waiting for each of them to arrive will lower the bandwidth.

You can use `hdparm -tT /dev/sd...`
You can also increase the size of dd buffer.

But you should test your disk with a disk benchmark like `bonnie++` or `iozone`.

Comment: hdparm gives me 400 - 1000 MB/s but why does moving a 20 GB file take 30 minutes?

Comment: Are you moving it on the same disk, on another disk? The  real speed vs disk raw speed could be affected (positively and negatively) by alignment, fragmentation, encryption, snapshot, compression, deduplication, caching, RAID level, mount options...

Comment: So first determine what is the raw speed of the disk (both for linear and random operations), then compare it with the current speed.

Comment: You can use `strace -c cp ....` to determine where the CPU time is spend (reads/writes vs userspace). Then you can use `sysdig`, `ftrace/trace-cmd` or `sytemtap` to see what is happening at the kernel level.